# Using BUFG to drive clock loads

Tags: buffer, vhdl, clock, xilinx-ise, spartan

I'm attempting to work with pixel data that is output to a DVI chip. A variety of clock frequencies are used because the DVI chip registers are programmed using I2C (therefore needs a clock < 500 KHz) - from a clock divider.

The DVI chip needs a 40 MHz differential pixel clock, however, the DVI takes displays half a byte twice a cycle, so a further 80 MHz clock is needed to push each half of the pixel onto the data lines with each half cycle, these are from a DCM.

This has led to a variety of problems. I attempted to just use the double pixel clock rate to swap each half of the pixel, however I got the error:

`This design contains a global buffer instance, <out2_bufg>,
   driving the net, <pxlclk_p_int>, that is driving the following (first 30)
   non-clock load pins.`

So I added a BUFG element between the output of the DCM and the components using the signal - but it hasn't changed anything, instead the error is now thrown twice on both the input and output of the BUFG.

- How can I fix this - given I've just added a BUFG and it doesn't like it!

My code is below; I've tried to cut out the unrelated things that aren't related to the clock but its still quite long!

EDIT 1: I have added the block, which when added to the system, caused the error (that wasn't there before) Its in the second block of code! I am currently working on the other suggestions RE the differential signalling, and will edit again when done!

Thanks very much,

David

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

ENTITY I2CBus IS
    PORT(
        SYSCLK_N   : IN    STD_LOGIC;   --system 200MHz differential clock
        SYSCLK_P   : IN    STD_LOGIC;
        BTN        : IN    STD_LOGIC;   -- to manually change reset

        LED        : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); --to observe reset value
        SCL_DBG    : OUT   STD_LOGIC;   -- copy of SCL to output pin
        SDA_DBG    : OUT   STD_LOGIC;   --copy of SDA to output pin
        SCL        : OUT   STD_LOGIC;   --Serial Clock Line
        SDA        : INOUT STD_LOGIC;   --Serial Data Line

        DVIRESET_N : OUT   STD_LOGIC;   --reset_n to dvi device
        DVI_ENABLE : OUT   STD_LOGIC;   --enable DVI device inputs (active high)
        PXLCLK_P   : OUT   STD_LOGIC;   --pixel clock differential pair through buffers
        PXLCLK_N   : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
        DVI_DATA   : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0); --12 bit multiplexed pixel to DVI
        HSYNC      : OUT   STD_LOGIC;   --Horizontal/Vertical sync timing pulses
        VSYNC      : OUT   STD_LOGIC
    );
END I2CBus;
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF I2CBus IS
    COMPONENT IIC_MASTER                --sends data to write out onto SDA bus line in I2C protocol
        PORT(SCL     : IN    STD_LOGIC;
             SCL2X   : IN    STD_LOGIC;
             RESET_N : IN    STD_LOGIC;
             ENA     : IN    STD_LOGIC;
             ADR     : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);
             REG     : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
             RW      : IN    STD_LOGIC;
             DAT_WR  : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
             BUSY    : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
             SDA     : INOUT STD_LOGIC;
             ACK_ERR : BUFFER STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT IIC_MASTER;
    COMPONENT DCM                       --takes input system differential clocks, generates further clocks
        PORT(
            SYSCLK_P : IN  STD_LOGIC;   -- CLOCK IN PORTS 200MHZ DIFFERENTIAL
            SYSCLK_N : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            -- CLOCK OUT PORTS
            SYSCLK   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            PXLCLK   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            PXLCLK2X : OUT STD_LOGIC
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT CLK_DIVIDER               --divides system clock down for i2c bus clock line
        GENERIC(INPUT_FREQ : INTEGER;
                OUT1_FREQ  : INTEGER;
                OUT2_FREQ  : INTEGER);
        PORT(SYSCLK      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             RESET_N     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             RESET_N_OUT : OUT STD_LOGIC;
             OUT1        : OUT STD_LOGIC;
             OUT2        : OUT STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT CLK_DIVIDER;

    COMPONENT DVI_INITIALISE            --initialises CH7301c registers to necessary operation values
        PORT(SYSCLK      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             ACK_ERR     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             BUSY        : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             RESET_N     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             COUNT       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
             DVI_WR      : OUT STD_LOGIC := '0';
             DVI_REGDATA : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
             DVI_WDATA   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
    END COMPONENT DVI_INITIALISE;

    COMPONENT DVI_INTERFACE             --outputs sync pulses, controls enable and manages pixel addresses
        PORT(PIXEL_CLK    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             RESET_N      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             PXL_ADDR     : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
             HSYNC, VSYNC : OUT STD_LOGIC                     := '1';
             ENABLE       : OUT STD_LOGIC                     := '0');
    END COMPONENT DVI_INTERFACE;

    COMPONENT DVI_MUX
        PORT(PXLCLK   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             PXLCLK2X : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             PXL_DAT  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(23 DOWNTO 0); --pixel as RGB
             DATA     : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0); --multiplexed output
             RESET_N  : IN  STD_LOGIC); --reset low signal
    END COMPONENT DVI_MUX;

    --Inputs
    signal reset_n_input : std_logic;   -- input reset from button

    ----Outputs ------
    signal sda_internal : STD_LOGIC;    -- Internal SDA

    ----Clocks-----
    signal SCL_internal   : std_logic;  -- i2c clock
    signal SCL2X_internal : std_logic;  -- i2c x2 to load SDA data
    signal sysclk         : std_logic;  --system clock
    signal pxlclk_p_int   : std_logic;  --differential pixel clock pair
    signal pxlclk_n_int   : std_logic;
    signal pxlclk         : std_logic;  --pxlclk after BUFG
    signal pxlclk2x_int   : STD_LOGIC;  --2x pixel clock for loading pixel data

    -----Internal Control Signals ---
    signal reset_n : std_logic;         --active high
    signal busy    : std_logic;         --low when not i2c not busy
    signal ack_err : std_logic;         --high when i2c ackknowledge error occurs

    ----Internal Data-----
    signal i2c_reg  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0); --register data for I2C
    signal i2c_rw   : STD_LOGIC;        --R/W* for I2C
    signal i2c_data : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0); --Data for I2C

BEGIN
    master : IIC_Master
        port map(
            SCL     => SCL_internal,
            SCL2X   => SCL2X_internal,
            RESET_N => RESET_N,
            ENA     => '1',
            ADR     => "1110110",
            REG     => i2c_reg,
            RW      => i2c_rw,
            DAT_WR  => i2c_data,
            BUSY    => busy,
            SDA     => sda_internal,
            ACK_ERR => ack_err
        );
    DCM_SYS : DCM
        port map(
            SYSCLK_P => SYSCLK_P,       --take differential input clock
            SYSCLK_N => SYSCLK_N,
            SYSCLK   => sysclk,         --200 MHz system clock 
            PXLCLK   => pxlclk,         --and pixel clock
            PXLCLK2X => pxlclk2x_int    --pixel clock at double rate
        );

    Clk_Div : Clk_Divider
        generic map(
            INPUT_FREQ => 200000000,    --200 MHz system input
            OUT1_FREQ  => 100000,       --to work correctly, 200 must go into all frequencies (x2).
            OUT2_FREQ  => 200000        --i.e. from 200, cannot generate 40 as 200/40/2 = 2.5, which will be 2
        )
        port map(
            SYSCLK      => sysclk,
            RESET_N     => reset_n_input,
            RESET_N_OUT => reset_n,
            OUT1        => scl_internal,
            OUT2        => scl2x_internal
        );

    data_load : component DVI_INITIALISE
        port map(
            SYSCLK      => sysclk,
            ACK_ERR     => ack_err,
            BUSY        => busy,
            RESET_N     => reset_n,
            COUNT       => LED,
            DVI_WR      => i2c_rw,
            DVI_REGDATA => i2c_reg,
            DVI_WDATA   => i2c_data
        );

    interface : DVI_INTERFACE
        port map(
            PIXEL_CLK => pxlclk_p_int,
            RESET_N   => reset_n,
            PXL_ADDR  => open,
            HSYNC     => HSYNC,
            VSYNC     => VSYNC,
            ENABLE    => DVI_ENABLE
        );

    pxl_mux : DVI_MUX
        port map(
            PXLCLK   => pxlclk_p_int,
            PXLCLK2X => pxlclk2x_int,
            PXL_DAT  => x"FF0000",
            DATA     => DVI_DATA,
            RESET_N  => reset_n
        );
    ------------OUTPUT BUFFERS (CLOCK FORWARDING)------------
    ODDR_pxlclk_p : ODDR2
        generic map(
            DDR_ALIGNMENT => "NONE",
            INIT          => '0',
            SRTYPE        => "SYNC")
        port map(
            Q  => PXLCLK_P,             --output to positive output
            C0 => pxlclk_p_int,         --differential input
            C1 => pxlclk_n_int,
            CE => '1',                  --chip enable tied high
            D0 => '1',
            D1 => '0',
            R  => '0',
            S  => '0'
        );

    ODDR_pxlclk_n : ODDR2
        generic map(
            DDR_ALIGNMENT => "NONE",
            INIT          => '0',
            SRTYPE        => "SYNC")
        port map(
            Q  => PXLCLK_N,             --output to negative output
            C0 => pxlclk_n_int,
            C1 => pxlclk_p_int,
            CE => '1',
            D0 => '1',
            D1 => '0',
            R  => '0',
            S  => '0'
        );

    out2_bufg : BUFG port map(I => pxlclk, O => pxlclk_p_int); --ERROR THROWN ON I/O HERE 
    ----------------Mappings---------------------------
    reset_n_input <= not BTN;           --when button pressed, reset
    SCL           <= 'Z' when scl_internal = '1' else scl_internal;
    SCL_DBG       <= 'Z' when scl_internal = '1' else scl_internal;
    SDA           <= sda_internal;
    SDA_DBG       <= SDA;               --copy SDA to debug line

    DVIRESET_N   <= reset_n;            --reset DVI device 
    pxlclk_n_int <= not pxlclk_p_int;   --create differential pair

end behavior;
```

**DVI_MUX** When I added this block to the system, the error was thrown where it previously wasnt

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY DVI_MUX IS
    PORT(
        PXLCLK   : IN  STD_LOGIC;       --pixel clock
        PXLCLK2X : IN  STD_LOGIC;       --double freq. pixel clock
        PXL_DAT  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(23 downto 0); --pixel in RGB format
        DATA     : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0); --
        RESET_N  : IN  STD_LOGIC
    );
END ENTITY DVI_MUX;

architecture RTL of DVI_Mux is
begin
    mux_proc : process(PXLCLK2X)
    begin
        if falling_edge(PXLCLK2X) then
            if PXLCLK = '0' then        -- if pxlclk low, load first half of pixel
                DATA <= PXL_DAT(23 downto 16) & PXL_DAT(11 downto 8);
            else    --else load second half
                DATA <= PXL_DAT(15 downto 12) & PXL_DAT(7 downto 0);
            end if;
            if RESET_N = '0' then --if reset active7
                DATA <= (others => '1');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture RTL;
```

Comment: The problem could also be within the components `DVI_INTERFACE` and `DVI_MUX`. The error method indicates that the clock signal is used as non-clock signal in combinational logic.

Comment: @MartinZabel I've put in the new block that triggered the error - but I don't see why just looking at the value of a clock should throw an error?

Comment: @davidhood2 thanks for the update, I updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it looks like you're trying to use a DDR output primitive to drive an external differential clock pin. This is a good thing to do, but the way you have done it seems unconventional. The standard way to do this would look more like this:

EDIT: I've realised that I misunderstood the question, and have incorporated the differential output instantiation from @StuartVivian

```
pxclk_inverted <= not pxlclk;

ODDR_pxlclk_p : ODDR2
    generic map(
        DDR_ALIGNMENT => "NONE",
        INIT          => '0',
        SRTYPE        => "SYNC")
    port map(
        Q  => PXLCLK_OUT,
        C0 => pxlclk,
        C1 => pxclk_inverted,
        CE => '1',
        D0 => '1',
        D1 => '0',
        R  => '0',
        S  => '0'
    );

inst_obufds : OBUFDS 
generic map (
  IOSTANDARD=>"LVDS_25"
) 
port map 
(
  O => PXLCLK_OUT_P, 
  OB  => PXLCLK_OUT_N, 
  I   => PXLCLK_OUT
);
```

In IO assignment, PXLCLK_OUT_N/P will then be set to use a differential IO standard. In a graphical pin assignment window, this port will then use two pins, and will only allow you to assign them to a valid positive/negative pair. What you're trying to do is manually create the positive and negative signals before the DDR output primitive, which is not the way it's supposed to work.

I think if you use this technique, and get rid of your `BUFG`, your problem should go away. If not, maybe update the question with this, and whatever the new problem might be.

---

Now that you've updated the question, I can see that your pixel output data also seems to be a DDR bus. You are trying to infer a DDR output behavior by implementing a multiplexer using a clock signal as the select line.

The more standard way to do this would be to instantiate *n* DDR output primitives, one for each bit of the parallel DDR output. According to the latest VHDL standard (VHDL2008) it is possible to infer a DDR output, but the problem with this is that this technique does not yet have widespread toolchain support.

Comment: Thanks ! - one question - how do I set differential io in the constraints ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using PlanAhead run from within Xilinx ISE for IO planning, in which case you just need to find the output in question, and use the IO standard drop down to select something differential.

Comment: @davidhood2 Using just two ODDR2 flip-flops is just fine. If you want to use the method posted by scary_jeff, then the you can also get the differential output by instantiating a `OBUFDS` between the output of the ODDR2 an the pins. Lookup [UG615 from Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/spartan6_hdl.pdf) for the description of `OBUFDS`.

Comment: I tried to change my top level to use the OBUFDS, but the chip differential clock is wired to pins C20 & C22 in bank 1 - and in the resources guide it says bank 1 doesn't support differential iostandards. However - I followed your advice, used a generate loop to create 11 ODDR's, hence although all the answers were all correct, I'm opting for this one as my chosen answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After that error message there would have been a list of up to 30 pins in the design that the tool believes you are driving with the clock but are not actual clock pins.

The C0 and C1 pins should be treated as clocks, so I doubt it's complaining about those. As the clock signal goes to other blocks which we haven't got the code for, could these contain end points for the clock that aren't clock pins?

I agree with scary_jeff's answer regarding the use of the ODDR2. To make a differential output from the output of the ODDR you need to instantiate a differential driver in the code i.e. LVDS_25 or LVDS in Xilinx architecture, and then set the logic standard in the ucf or xdc/sdc constraints files. The tools documentation should give clear examples of this.

```
inst_obufds : OBUFDS 
generic map ( IOSTANDARD=>"LVDS_25" ) 
port map 
(    O => DIFF_P, 
     OB  => DIFF_N, 
     I   => internal_signal
);
```

Comment: There was no list of pins after the message (I looked) - but am working on changing the system to use the OBUFDS!

Comment: I realised that my answer didn't actually provide the differential output required, so I added your differential buffer instantiation to my answer and upvoted yours, I hope this was an OK thing to do.

Comment: I've just edited my code to reflect this - but the pins I need to output my differential pair too (C20 & C22) are located on Bank 1 and thus LVDS_25 isn't allowed. Any ideas?

Comment: To use a diff output the two pins must be part of a P-N pair. The logic standard used needs to use compatible supply voltages with all the other IOs in the bank. Support also depends on the device you are using. 7-series have two different types of general IO bank HR (high range) and HP (high performance). HR can use 2.5V Vcc and therefore uses LVDS_25. HP can use 1.8V for LVDS and I believe the IO standard string for that is "LVDS". Spartans are different again. Look in the DC characteristics user guide for the device you are targeting for the supported standards.

Answer (score 3):

The message is reported because `pxlclk` is used to drive the multiplexer in the component of `DVI_MUX` and this multiplexer is placed before the flipflop. To reach the select signal of the multiplexer, the signal `pxlclk` must use the general purpose routing instead of the dedicated clock tree. Please read [UG381 from Xilinx, pp. 61/62](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug381.pdf#61) on how the Spartan-6 supports DDR outputs.

I recommentd to use the `ODDR2` component also for the data pins. The inputs `D0` and `D1` just provide the data which should be output with the rising edge of clock `C0` and `C1` respectivly. Please lookup the [UG615  from Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/spartan6_hdl.pdf) for a thruth table and more information.
If the documentation seems to be unclear, I recommend to simulate the component `DVI_MUX` standalone first.