# Output an internal fabric clock to LVDS (xilinx zynq device)

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to push my fabric clock to an output LVDS pair on a ZedBoard. I am using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224593/using-bufg-to-drive-clock-loads) by scary_jeff.

FCLK_CLK1 is using a DDR PLL set to 150 MHz. I created a testbench for the IP which shows the expeceted output (the lvds pairs following the input clock with the expected inversion between the pairs).

The vhdl used to generate the ip :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.Vcomponents.all;

entity clk_to_lvds_v1_0 is
    port (
        clk_in  : in std_logic;
        clk_out_p : out std_logic;
        clk_out_n : out std_logic
    );
end clk_to_lvds_v1_0;

architecture arch_imp of clk_to_lvds_v1_0 is

signal clk_buf : std_logic;
signal clk_inv : std_logic;

begin

-- V1
--    oddr_inst : oddr
--    generic map(
--        DDR_CLK_EDGE => "SAME_EDGE",
--        INIT => '0',
--        SRTYPE => "SYNC"
--    )
--    port map (
--        Q => clk_buf,
--        C => clk_in,
--        CE => '1',
--        D1 => '1',
--        D2 => '0',
--        R => '0',
--        S => '0'
--    );

-- V2

clk_inv <= not clk_in;

ODDR_pxlclk_p : ODDR2
generic map(
    DDR_ALIGNMENT => "NONE",
    INIT          => '0',
    SRTYPE        => "SYNC")
port map(
    Q  => clk_buf,
    C0 => clk_in,
    C1 => clk_inv,
    CE => '1',
    D0 => '1',
    D1 => '0',
    R  => '0',
    S  => '0'
);

    obufds_inst : obufds
    generic map ( IOSTANDARD=>"LVDS_25" ) 
    port map(
        O  => clk_out_p,
        OB => clk_out_n,
        I  => clk_buf
    );

end arch_imp;
```

The output is being pushed to JC1_P/N pmod ports using LVDS_25 standard.

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AB7 [get_ports {clk_out_p[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVDS_25 [get_ports {clk_out_p[0]}]
```

I am measuring the output with a scope (6 GHz, 20 GS/s) and all I'm seeing is  noise. I turned on some LEDs in the design to ensure that the bitstream is being loaded properly.

Is this still the preferred method by Xilinx to output a clock on I/O?

[image: vivado design]

Comment: Yes, the method presented by @scary_jeff is correct. Can you confirm that Vivado applied your placement constraints to the pins e.g. by reviewing the reports and by reviewing the used wires and pads in device view? Can you connect a simple counter of >15 bits (depends on your frequency) to that clock and display the most significant bit on an LED? If you clock is toggling, the counter should count and the MSB lets the LED blink.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem in a Kintex UltraScale design (diff clock output, but just noise). I never figured out why, because we solved the original problem, so the missing differential clock signal was not further investigated :(.

Comment: @Paebbels I added a 1 Hz LED output on the same FCLK source as the one I am attempting to output. It is blinking but I am still seeing nothing but noise on the scope. I switched the output to an OBUF instead of OBUFDS just to mix things up. Verified the correct placement in the IO REPORT... Not sure what to try at this point.

Comment: So what does it look like with 100 ohms between clock_out_p and clock_out_n?

Comment: What user1155120 is saying is a good point: are you using a differential probe with termination to measure the output? Else you should terminate the HF signal manually to prevent reflections.

Comment: I am using a differential probe with termination. 

Using another board with a zynq 7020 on it that also has an external oscillator I used the Xilinx clock wizard to generate a 200 MHz clock from the oscillator and routed it directly to a obufds and was able to see the signal. It seems the issue stems directly from using a zynq internal PLL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I wasn't initializing the ps7_init on the ARM cores which kicks the clocks off. After doing that I saw the output clock on a scope.

Comment: That’s true, fclk coming out the Zynq cpu is gated if you are not booting Linux or running code on them...  better to use a board clock connected to Programmable logic as a reference clock.